# Using beginner python and parallel lists to find frequency of dysfunctional alleles in a population

Tags: python, loops, bioinformatics, biopython

Let's say I have a database DNA sequences from 90 people

seqList, a list, contains:

**Seq1: ATGGGGGTTAAGGATA**

**Seq2: GCCACACTTTGGGGGA**

**Seq3: AGTAAAAGAACACACA... and so on until Seq90**

Each separate sequence of the 90 is known as a **variant**

I have been given a list that gives positions within these DNA sequences where mutations regularly occur

**slim_pos** = [0,4,10,13] -> in ALL 90 sequences referred to above, these are the indices of where mutations typically happen.

So for Seq1, the nucleotides/positions affected would be [A,G,A,A]. Pattern continues for all 90 sequences.

I have also been given a list called **dys_nuc, that runs parallel to slim_pos**. They have the same length and are entirely corresponding.

**dys_nuc** = ['A','T', 'A', 'A'] <- these nucleotides (the letters) match up with the positions listed in slim_pos. dys_nuc is a list that details the nucelotides in these positions where mutations occurs that are associated with dysfunction and disease.

My task is to find the frequency of people that have dysfunctional nucleotides the positions otulined by slim_pos. There are 90 different people/sequences, and I want to know the frequency of the dysfunctional mutations at those sites in the entire population.

I am very new to python and am completely stuck on how to go about this. I've been at it for 2 days now and think I need some help... Below is some code showing what I have to this point.  It does not work because of a list indexing error, but this is more to show you how I am thinking of approaching the problem. My first thought was to make a counter (dysfunctional_counter) to record where each variant had a dysfunctional mutation in the defined mutation sites and calculate frequencies using this counter somehow.. but I am completely lost now and confused.

```
dysfunctional_count=[]
normal_count =[]
count = [] 
for variant in seqList:
    for(ind, val) in enumerate(slim_pos):
        if variant[val] == dys_nuq[ind]:
            count[ind] += 1
           # dysfunctional_count[variant] += 1
        else:
            normal_count[variant] += 1
```

Eventually, I am hoping to create an output like this:

| Dysfunctional Sequence Site (this is slim_pos) | Dysfunctional nucleotide | Frequency of population who have dysfunctional nucleotide in the sequence site |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 0.06666666666666667 |
| 4 | T | 0.011111111111111112 |
| 10 | A | 0.011111111111111112 |
| 14 | A | 0.03333333333333333 |

Any guidance is very much appreciated :)

Comment: This looks at least approximately right to me. You don't really need `normal_count`, for each mutation the `normal_count` should equal `len(seqList) - count[ind]`, but the basic approach (iterate through each sequence/mutation pair with a nested loop, counting the number of sequences that have the specified mutation) looks fine. Can you narrow down your question? What isn't working about that approach?

Comment: Oh, btw, your list indexing error is likely from not having `count` initialized. You can pre-size it with 0s, `count = [0 for _ in range(len(slim_pos))]` is one way. `count = [0] * len(slim_pos)` will work too and is safe in this context, but that idiom will get you in trouble if you use it to prepopulate a list with mutable objects like other lists. Or you could use a dict instead of a list, `count = {}`, a list is more efficient for integer indexing if it's not going to be sparse but that doesn't matter at this scale.

Comment: this is what I get for an error:

  File "<ipython-input-122-9c7bffc26447>", line 10, in <module>
    count[ind] += 1

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That should go away if you prepopulate `count` (and `normal_count` if you keep it) with 0s - we crossed paths typing those comments. If you use a dict instead, `count[ind] = count.get(ind, 0) + 1` is how I'd do it. Or use a `collections.defaultdict` set to default to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The index error you're seeing is because you start with an empty list `count` and try to index into it. You also define `normal_count` as a list, but the index you're using is of type `str`. I would personally use dictionaries for this, and to make lookup after easier.

```
dys_count = {dys: 0 for dys in dys_nuq} 
for variant in seqList:
    for(ind, val) in enumerate(slim_pos):
        if variant[val] == dys_nuq[ind]:
            dys_count[dys_nuq[ind]] += 1
```

Then, all you have to do is look up each nucleotide by name. For example

```
freq = dys_count['A'] / len(seqList)
```

Or, if you wanted to loop over all the data

```
for nucl, occur in dys_count.items():
    print(f'Nucleotide {nucl} was found {occur} times')
```